# VIM autocompletion: Making ^X^U expand to longest match

Tags: vim

I'm using eclim to bring some eclipse functionality to VIM, however the code completion functions seem to work less than ideal. When I press ctrl+x ctrl+u after, for instance, System.out. with the curser right after the last dot, I get the completion popup-menu. This menu is really rather cumbersome to use, and the functionality that I would ideally want is something like:

ctrl+x ctrl+u (expands to longest match) fill in more characters  (expand to longest match). Is this possible somehow? I've tried fiddling with the completeopts settings, but they don't seem to do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So does

```
:set completeopt=longest
```

not do roughly what you need?

Comment: It does, apparently SuperTab was messing up its functionality. Thanks.